# Have moderator flags show up in StackExchange inbox?

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, stackexchange-2.0, global-inbox, flags

I really, really am appreciating the global inbox, but as a mod I find the one thing missing is moderator flags.  I think these should show up in the inbox, and perhaps even be a different color, so that I can quickly address any flags on the site I moderate, even if I'm on meta.

Comment: +1 - I can't say it's an issue for me, though.  That could be because I'm not a mod on any of the sites.

Comment: Not sure if it's always been there, but there's a flag count (that links to the flag dashboard) in the top bar of your site. Or is this specifically about seeing those flags listed somewhere universal, so they're accessible even when not directly viewing the site?

Answer (score 9):

From what Joel and Bill said, it looks like there could end up being quite noisy in the Inbox if mod flags were in it.  However, there's still a lot of room in that SE box; the team could quite easily fit an extra tab option, something along the lines of:

[image]

This would offer more flexibility with sorting, too.  For instance, you could sort on number of flags (I would expect more flags to have a higher priority).

Comment: This would work quite well for those of us who are mods on multiple sites.

Answer (score 4):

I like the idea as well, but then I'm only a mod here on meta where traffic is relatively low.  I think we need to hear from one of the mods on the main Stack Overflow site, where there are a lot more flags, before I can really get behind this.

Comment: I'm torn.  On one hand it would be a lot of noise in the global inbox, but on the other hand I don't use many other sites so I don't have a lot of signal in the global inbox anyway.  (Sorry, I'm trying to find a gripping hand here, but there doesn't seem to be one.)

Comment: @Bill: Now I'm going to have nightmares about Moties again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Bill: flags don't have to count as the number of notifications; if you have no messages but flags it can say 0, and when you feel like checking flags you can open the dropdown and see

Comment: @Kop: That would work.  I definitely don't want notifications on mod flags, since 1) those come in torrents on SO, and 2) other mods clear them too, not just me.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to propose an alternative way for this.

Instead of showing the flags in the Global Inbox/Notification multicollider, I'd like to see the flags in the usual place.

So, if I moderate 1 or 5 sites it won't matter. If I get a flag on one of my sites, and I'm visiting another one, I'd like to see the yellow circle in the usual place. Clicking on the circle will always bring me to the usual place to moderate.

Advantages I see:

- I can quickly handle flags because I'd see them regardless of the site I'm visiting (even if I forget to visit my own site that day);
- It makes moderation quicker and easier, without forcing me to visit my site to see flags.

While it's true that Moderation is not just about handling flags, I don't think this would (should) make moderators do *less*. It's just a way to speed up the process of checking and handling flags **and not an excuse to avoid doing the other things**: like visiting the site you moderate, editing, closing, etc.

Moderators **should always visit their site**, but if I just opened the computer in the morning checking SE, I'd like to instantly know if something was flagged even if I'm visiting a totally unrelated site.

It's just a way to speed up our duties, not give us the excuse to ignore the other ones which are as important.